# Unable to insert HTML5 tags into HTML Component in Community Builder

Tags: community, html, community-builder

I am trying to insert `<header>`, `<polygon>` and `<path>` tags into my HTML Editor component within a community, however I get an error highlighting these tags are unsupported.

Is there anyway I can add these tags?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the support for HTML5 components go, 2/3 of your tags do not seem supported.

- `<polygon>`
- `<path>`

For a complete list of suported tags, you can check [forcedotcom/aura](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura/src/main/java/org/auraframework/def/HtmlTag.java) github repo for supported tags. The reference can also be found in the [Lightning Component Dev. Guide - Supported HTML Tags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags.htm)

Basically, you can't add these tags in your component markup, you will keep running into the following Error:

> Failed to save ComponentName.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://polygon
>   found : [markup://c:ComponentName]: Source

Unless added to the supportd tags in the framework.

Comment: Is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: no (or at least not that I am aware of), can wait for someone else to post another answer